# Getting the most out of an ancillary shield booster

Tags: eve-online

I've been messing around with the following Slasher fit in EFT for a while now, and I had a question re: the effectiveness of the ASB.

```
[Slasher, Mosquito-Fit]
Damage Control II
Micro Auxiliary Power Core I

Limited 1MN Afterburner I
J5b Phased Prototype Warp Scrambler I
Medium Ancillary Shield Booster, Cap Booster 50
Cap Recharger II

5W Infectious Power System Malfunction
125mm Light 'Scout' Autocannon I, Republic Fleet Phased Plasma S
125mm Light 'Scout' Autocannon I, Republic Fleet Phased Plasma S
125mm Light 'Scout' Autocannon I, Republic Fleet Phased Plasma S

Small Anti-EM Screen Reinforcer I
Small Anti-EM Screen Reinforcer I
Small Anti-Thermal Screen Reinforcer I
```

Would the ASB be more effective in a fight if I were to raise my shield resists with rigs and a Damage Control the way I've got it set up here, or does it not matter?

I've always assumed that you'd want to pair any local reps with a good omni-tank to improve its effectiveness, specifically to reduce incoming damage so that your rep can cover it - am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Raising your resists will pretty much always help you tank more damage. By decreasing the amount of resisted damage, less 'real' damage hits your shield, so the ASB effectively reps more damage.

from the [UniWiki on Shield Tanking](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Shield_Tanking#Fitting_Strategy):

> Imagine you have a shield booster that repairs 100 points per cycle. If someone 
>   deals you 1000 points of EM damage, to which you have a 10% resistance, will result 
>   in 900 points of shield damage. Your shield booster will repair this in 9 cycles.
>   If someone deals you 1000 points of explosive damage to which you have 70% 
>   resistance, you'll only sustain 300 points of shield damage, which the shield 
>   booster will fix in three cycles.
>
> So you would use three times as much energy, and take three times as long to repair the EM damage because of the lack of resistance.

Also, you have the smallest available charge for it loaded. Good.

Comment: I haven't touched eve in a while, and I've never run a shield-boosted setup on any of my rides. Why are you saying that it's good to have the "smallest" charge on the shield injector?

Comment: The size of the charge has no effect on the amount of shield restored by the ASB, as such you always want to load the smallest size available in order to maximize the number of cycles you get before you have to reload